# Combining 2 lists in Lisp

Tags: lisp

From 2 simple lists (e.g. (1 2 3) and (a b c)) I am trying to create a list of lists ((1 a) (2 b) (3 c)). However, following code is not working:

```
(defun comblist_op (list1 list2)
(let ((combl '()))
    (loop for i in list1 do(
        loop for j in list2 do(
                (push (list i j) combl))))
    combl))
```

The error is:

```
*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (PUSH (LIST I J) COMBL) should be a lambda expression
```

Do I need to write lambda expression here?

Comment: Your code is still not properly formatted. Please take the effort to format your code. Instead of creating lots of trivial syntax errors, like misplaced parentheses in poorly formatted code, I propose that you actually take the time to read a basic Lisp introduction. Here is a good one: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nested loops, just one loop that iterates over `list` and `list2` at the same time. Nested loops will make a cross-product, not just combine corresponding elements.

The error you're getting is because you're putting an extra set of parentheses around the expressions after `do`. It doesn't require you to wrap them up.

```
(defun comblist (list1 list2) 
  (let ((combl '()))
    (loop for i in list1
          for j in list2
        do (push (list i j) combl))
    (nreverse combl)))
```

You need to reverse the result list because `PUSH` will create it in the reverse order than the original lists.

You can also use the built-in `COLLECT` operator of `LOOP`.

```
(defun comblist (list1 list2) 
    (loop for i in list1
          for j in list2
        collect (list i j)))
```

If you want all the combinations of the elements from the two lists, nested loops will work. Just fix the problem with the extra parentheses around the `DO` expressions.

```
(defun comblist (list1 list2) 
  (let ((combl '()))
    (loop for i in list1
      do
        (loop for j in list2
          do
            (push (list i j) combl)))
    combl))
```

Comment: Your nested loops will produce that result. You just need to fix the `DO` syntax.

Comment: I expect them to be `((1 3) (2 4))`. The loop ends when the end of the shorter list is reached.